# Javascript filtering nested arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to filter a on a nested array inside an array of objects in an Angular app. Here's a snippet of the component code -

```
var teams = [
  { name: 'Team1', members: [{ name: 'm1' }, { name: 'm2' }, { name: 'm3' }] }, 
  { name: 'Team2', members: [{ name: 'm4' }, { name: 'm5' }, { name: 'm6' }] }, 
  { name: 'Team3', members: [{ name: 'm7' }, { name: 'm8' }, { name: 'm9' }] }
];
```

What I'm trying to achieve is if I search for `m5` for example my result should be -

```
var teams = [
  { name: 'Team1', members: [] }, 
  { name: 'Team2', members: [{ name: 'm5' }] }, 
  { name: 'Team3', members: [] }
];
```

So I've got `teams` and `filteredTeams` properties and in my search function I'm doing -

```
onSearchChange(event: any): void {
  let value = event.target.value;
  this.filteredTeams = this.teams.map(t => {
    t.members = t.members.filter(d => d.name.toLowerCase().includes(value));
    return t;
  })
}
```

Now this does work to some extent however because I'm replacing the members it's destroying the array on each call (if that makes sense). I understand why this is happening but my question is what would be the best way to achieve this filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you were very close, the only thing that you did wrong was *mutating* the source objects in `teams`

basically you can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to generate a new entry and then return a whole new array with new values.

```js
const teams = [
  { name: 'Team1', members: [{ name: 'm1' }, { name: 'm2' }, { name: 'm3' }] }, 
  { name: 'Team2', members: [{ name: 'm4' }, { name: 'm5' }, { name: 'm6' }] }, 
  { name: 'Team3', members: [{ name: 'm7' }, { name: 'm8' }, { name: 'm9' }] }
];

const value = 'm5';

const result = teams.map(t => {
  const members = t.members.filter(d => d.name.toLowerCase().includes(value));
  return { ...t, members };
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Instead of hard coded `m5` pass your value.

```js
const teams = [
  { name: 'Team1', members: [{ name: 'm1' }, { name: 'm2' }, { name: 'm3' }] }, 
  { name: 'Team2', members: [{ name: 'm4' }, { name: 'm5' }, { name: 'm6' }] }, 
  { name: 'Team3', members: [{ name: 'm7' }, { name: 'm8' }, { name: 'm9' }] }
];

const filteredTeams = teams.map(team => ({ name: team.name, members: team.members.filter(member => member.name.includes('m5')) }));

console.log(filteredTeams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the original objects, but you could assing new properties to the result object for mapping instead.

```js
var teams = [{ name: 'Team1', members: [{ name: 'm1' }, { name: 'm2' }, { name: 'm3' }] }, { name: 'Team2', members: [{ name: 'm4' }, { name: 'm5' }, { name: 'm6' }] }, { name: 'Team3', members: [{ name: 'm7' }, { name: 'm8' }, { name: 'm9' }] }],
    result = teams.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        { members: o.members.filter(({ name }) => name === 'm5') }
    ));
    
console.log(result);
console.log(teams);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to seperate your filter function first:

```
const filterTeamMembers = (teams, filterArr) => {
    const useFilter = filterArr.map(x => x.toLowerCase());

    return teams.map(team => ({
        ...team,
        members: team.members.filter(member => useFilter.includes(member.name))
    }))
};
// =========== And then:

onSearchChange(event: any): void {
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.filteredTeams = filterTeamMembers(this.teams, [value]);
}
```