# Filter an nested Object with filter and map with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know that this is close to a duplicate but I can't get the code to work.  I have an object that I need to filter and I'm currently trying to emulate the accepted as an answer the code at [Javascript filtering nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555942/javascript-filtering-nested-arrays)

My data object is:

```
[{
    "project_num": "5R01DA012513-23",
    "principal_investigators": [{
      "profile_id": 2076451,
      "full_name": "PK",
      "title": ""
    }]
  },
  {
    "project_num": "5R01DK118529-03",
    "principal_investigators": [{
      "profile_id": 8590844,
      "full_name": "HW",
      "title": "PROFESSOR, SCIENTIFIC DIRECTOR"
    }]
  },
  {
    "project_num": "3R01AA025365-05S1",
    "principal_investigators": [{
      "profile_id": 8730036,
      "full_name": "JJ",
      "title": "ASSOCIATE PROFESSOR OF PSYCHIATRY"
    }]
  },
  {
    "project_num": "1R01HL163963-01",
    "principal_investigators": [{
        "profile_id": 2084037,

        "full_name": "KH",
        "title": "ASSOCIATE PROFESSOR"
      },
      {
        "profile_id": 11309656,
        "full_name": "AM",
        "title": "RESEARCH ASSISTANT PROFESSOR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "project_num": "5R25HL092611-15",
    "principal_investigators": [{
      "profile_id": 1886512,
      "full_name": "CW",
      "title": "P"
    }]
  }
]
```

and my JavaScript code is:

```
let payLoad = 1886512
const result = this.reporterData.map(t => {
  const principal_investigators = t.principal_investigators.filter(d =>
    d.profile_id === payLoad);
  return { ...t,
    principal_investigators
  };
})
```

I need to pass in a profile_id as a payload and return the objects that will fill a data table.

The data can be 1000's of items and the principla_investigators can be multiple entries.  When I use the code that I have it return all of the objects. Can someone point out my error?  Thanks

Comment: What result are you trying to get, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: What is payload?

Comment: The JS has mismatched brackets.

Comment: When I pass in the profile_id I would like to only get back the objects with that profile_id in the principal_investigator.  I am currently getting back the the entire reporterData object-- over 500 records payload is the profile_id variable passed in from a different function.  I should have cleaned that up

Comment: Then you should be filtering the `reporterData` array, not mapping it, if you don't want to get back all the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing like this:

```
const result = this.reporterData.filter((t) => {
  const principal_investigators = t.principal_investigators.filter((d) => d.profile_id === payLoad)
  return (principal_investigators.length > 0)
})
```

Comment: Sorry- but I don't get any results returned

Comment: Check edited answer.

Comment: I don't think your edits should make any difference.

Comment: Instead of `filter()` and `length`, you can use the `some()` method. But it looks like this should work.

Comment: @Bill It works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/b52fa30m/

Comment: It is encouraged to also add brackets around your arrow function arguments when you have just one argument (it's mandatory when using multiple arguments). This keeps your code consistent and easier to read.

Comment: @Jasper In general we don't edit to change code style. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351501/conventional-improvements-of-readability-are-not-deemed-to-make-the-code-even-a

Comment: @barmar: I know: my edit was to add a missing } which broke the code, meaning the answer would not work, but edits need to be at least 6 characters so I also changed some codestyle to match es6 best practices ;)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want an array with all the investigators matching that ID, right?

Try this:

```
const result = this.reporterData.reduce((previous, current) => {
    if (current.principal_investigators) {
        current.principal_investigators.forEach(pi => {
            if (pi.profile_id === payLoad) {
                previous.push(current)
            }
        });
    }
    return previous
}, [])
```

You can also do for loops with the same result:

```
const result = [];
for (project of this.reporterData) {
    if (project.principal_investigators) {
        for (pi of project.principal_investigators) {
            if (pi.profile_id == payLoad) {
                result.push(pi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```